# Spring JDBC connections left open

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I'm using the following bean to connect to the DB through JDBC:

```
<bean id="databaseds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="2" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="0" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="120000" />
</bean>
```

Using quartz a new class is constructed which takes advantage of Spring JDBC to run SQL statements. What I did notice is that most of the the JDBC connections are still hanging around hours after the quartz job ran and completed. Based on the bean I'm expecting to have NO idle sessions 2-3 minutes after the connection is not being used.

Am I missing anything? I don't want to keep more than 1-2 connections open to the database, the program is not doing any DB intensive work but does run every 30 minutes and if the connections are not reused or closed they pile up.

Comment: Where are you managing the transactionability of your connections? Can you provide some code to replicate the issue?

Comment: Not sure, but you might need to set `testWhileIdle` in order for the "evictor thread" to be started. Also, did you remember to close the connection at the end of your background job?

Comment: How are you obtaining a reference to this datasource? You aren't consrtucting a new `ApplicationContext` each time you start a new quartz job?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, not sure how easily it can be replicated, also I'm not doing any connections management or working with transactions.

Comment: @Andreas I really looked for a way to close the connection but I can't find a way - everywhere I look I find that sprint will do that automatically

Comment: Well, provide the code and configuration you're using. This can be done if you try to replicate the issue in a new project without too much noise (irrelevant code/configurations), maybe when trying to replicate the issue you find the answer, if not post it here.

Comment: @M.Deinum

I'm doing: 

scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
..
JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
...
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
...
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

Comment: Please don't add code as comments as that is unreadable, please improve your question. Also what you show is about scheduling a job but I'm interested in what happens INSIDE that job...

Comment: inside the job I always create a new ApplicationContext, I also added the code to close the ApplicationContect - but the JDBC connections still hang around. If I kill the java program the JDBC connections drop, but I need them to drop when the context is closed, or the job is finished/